# MySQL stored procedure runs on v5.6.16 but got 1064 syntax error on v5.1.45

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a pivot table view with below stored procedure. It worked on Mac OS X, MySQL ver 5.6.16. But when I created the same procedure on Windows, MySQL ver 5.1.45, there's error message:

*PREPARE stmt FROM @sql   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1*

Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`crossover`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getPatientTestRecordsEid`(IN varPid int, IN varTid int)
BEGIN

SET @sql = NULL;
SET @myPid = varPid;
SET @myTid = varTid;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN TestDate = ''', TestDate,
                ''' THEN TestResult END) `', TestDate, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM 
(select 
date_format(Test_Record.Date, "%Y-%m-%d") As TestDate, 
Test_Item.EID AS TestItem, 
Test_Record_Detail.Result AS TestResult
from
Test_Record, Test_Record_Detail, Test_Item
where
Test_Record.TR_ID = Test_Record_Detail.TR_ID AND
Test_Item.EID = Test_Record_Detail.EID AND
Test_Record.PID = @myPid AND
Test_Record.TID = @myTid) As t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT TestItem, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM 
(select 
date_format(Test_Record.Date, "%Y-%m-%d") As TestDate, 
Test_Item.EID AS TestItem, 
Test_Record_Detail.Result AS TestResult
from
Test_Record, Test_Record_Detail, Test_Item
where
Test_Record.TR_ID = Test_Record_Detail.TR_ID AND
Test_Item.EID = Test_Record_Detail.EID AND
Test_Record.PID = @myPid AND
Test_Record.TID = @myTid) As t 

GROUP BY TestItem');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: You don't define a data type for your variables: `SET @sql = NULL;`

Comment: Tried SET @sql = "";. Doesn't work.

Comment: hi juergen, I tried to change the "SET" to "declare mySQL varchar(3000);", but then "prepare stmt from mySql" will fail. Could you give me more hints? thanks.

Comment: Can you show the content of the user-defined variable `@sql`?

Comment: SELECT @sql would get NULL return. Finally figure out the foreign key is not set as development server. Thanks for your hint.